# Execute command with multiple layers of quoting via ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, quoting

I want to execute a docker command on a remote server. The problem is I don't know to escape multiple quotes.

```
ret=$(ssh root@server "docker exec nginx bash -c 'cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep 'ServerName' | cut -d '|' -f1'")
```

I get

```
bash:  -f1: command not found
```

Comment: The best way to handle quoting is to eliminate the need for it. Can you use `docker --host server exec ...` to connect to the remote Docker instance? You can almost certainly replace the `bash` shell and its explicit pipeline with a single command `awk -F'|' '/ServerName {print $1}'`, leaving you with something like `docker --host server exec "awk -F "|" '/ServerName/ {print \$1}' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"`.

Comment: Your [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71053255/4) of the question was easier to understand. I'd recommend reverting your latest edit as it's hard to comprehend and potentially invalidates the existing answers. If you have a follow-up question it would be better to post a new question.

Comment: okey, I create a new post :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your parameter string with N calls to `"$(printf "%q" ...)"`, for N recursive calls .

```
ssh root@server "docker exec nginx bash -c 'cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep ServerName | cut -d | -f1'"
```

How may recursive calls the above line has? I don't wish to set up docker just for the test, so I may have one of the following wrong:

1. ssh  - certainly counts
2. docker - ??
3. ngix  - ??
4. bash  - certainly counts

If there are four, then you need four calls to `"$(printf "%q "str")"`, don't forget to add all those `"` marks

```
ssh root@server docker exec nginx bash -c "$(printf "%q" "$(printf "%q" "$(printf "%q" "$(printf "%q" "cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep ServerName | cut -d | -f1")")")")"
```

Explanation: `ssh` parses the string like `bash -c` does, stripping one level of quotes. docker and nginx may also each parse the string (or not). Finally, `bash -c` parses whatever the previous levels have parsed, and removes the final level of quotes. `exec` does not parse the strings, it simply passes them verbatim to the next level.

Another solution is to put the line, that you want bash to execute, into a script. Then you can simply invoke the script without all this quoting insanity.

```
#!/bin/bash
< /etc/nginx/nginx.conf grep ServerName | cut -d | -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

There's little need to execute so much on the remote host. The file you want to search isn't likely that big: just pipe the entire thing down via `ssh` to a local `awk` process:

```
ret=$(ssh root@server "docker exec nginx cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf" |
         awk -F'|' '/ServerName/ {print $1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `here-document` :

```
ret="$(ssh root@server << 'EOF'
docker exec nginx bash -c "grep 'ServerName' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | cut -d '|' -f1"
EOF
)"
echo "$ret"
```

Or, simpler as suggested by @MichaelVeksler :

```
ret="$(ssh root@server docker exec -i nginx bash << 'EOF'
grep 'ServerName' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | cut -d '|' -f1
EOF
)"
echo "$ret"
```

Comment: I think you mean `ret="$(ssh root@server docker exec nginx bash << 'EOF' \n "grep 'ServerName' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | cut -d '|' -f1" \n EOF \n )"`  (comments don't support newlines, so consider each `\n` to be a newline

Comment: Thanks for your replying, How to execute a variable on EOF block